# Add Newline after addChild() in simplexml_load_file php

Tags: php, xml

I have added a new child in existing xml file using `simplexml_load_file()` function..But it doesn't come as formatted thing..
I have tried this code

```
   `$file = 'data/users.xml';
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($file);
    $xml->Users;
    $newuser = $xml->addChild('userdata');
    $newuser->addChild('userid', $data['id']);
    $newuser->addChild('name', $data['name']);
    $newuser->addChild('email', $data['email']);
    $newuser->addChild('mobile', $data['mobile']);
    $newuser->addChild('username', $data['user']);
    $newuser->addChild('password', $data['pass']);
    $newuser->addChild('role', $data['role']);

    $dom = dom_import_simplexml($xml)->ownerDocument;
    $dom->formatOutput = TRUE;
    $dom->save($file);`
```

Result is

```
`<userdata><name>agallery</name><filepath>path/to/gallery</filepath>
 <thumb>mythumb.jpg</thumb></userdata>`
```

But i need it as formatted like this

```
`<userdata>
 <name>agallery</name>
 <filepath>path/to/gallery</filepath>
 <thumb>mythumb.jpg</thumb>
 </userdata>`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formatting of a document isn't important when it comes to XML, although it normally tends to be presented in a structured laid out format.  SimpleXML doesn't have an option to do this ( AFAIK ) so you may have to use DOM to do this...

```
$dom = dom_import_simplexml($xml)->ownerDocument;
$dom->formatOutput = TRUE;
$dom->save($file);
```

This takes the document, converts it to DOM and then formats the output.

EDIT:These is a common problem that the formatting just doesn't seem to work at times, the workaround seems excessive, but that's what workarounds sometimes end up as...

```
$dom = dom_import_simplexml($xml)->ownerDocument;
$dom->formatOutput = true;
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->loadXML( $dom->saveXML());
$dom->save($file);
```

Comment: in your answer `$dom` variable represents?

Comment: $dom is created as a DOMDocument (the DOMElement returned from `dom_import_simplexml`, is then used to fetch the owner document). It is simply a copy of your SimpleXML document.

Comment: please c my updated question code..stil it has come as like as old result..is there anything i missed?

Comment: I've updated code and checked it with your source - the answer isn't ideal, but it seems to work.